# Use an SVG with external definitions

Tags: html, svg

Let's say I have an SVG file. It references an external CSS stylesheet as well as an external SVG file. Here's a shortened version.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="svg.css"?>
<svg version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <use xlink:href="defs.svg#myDefs" />
   <g>
      <path class="someClass" d="all the points" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

The external CSS file provides some styling:

```
.someClass {
   fill: url(#someGradient);
}
```

And the external referenced SVG file provides the definition needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
   <defs id="myDefs">
      <linearGradient id="someGradient" x1="100%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
         <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color: red;" />
         <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color: white;" />
      </linearGradient>
   </defs>
</svg>
```

Finally, the SVG file is loaded into the DOM in a way that it is allowed to interact with other files.

```
<object data="someFile.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

In Edge/Chrome's network inspector I can see that all files are loaded by the browser including the SVG, the referenced external CSS file and the referenced external SVG file containing the definitions. But I'm not getting this to work properly. When I take the `<defs>` and move them into the SVG file being displayed then all works properly. This tells me that the CSS file is being loaded correctly and is working. The `<defs>` file is not.

Is it possible to load another SVG not for a specific image in that SVG but instead solely for the definitions contained within it? I've tried putting the gradient name in the `use` link as well as giving the `<defs>` an ID like I did here.

Why would I want to do this? Because I have dozens of SVG files that are interactive. As a user does certain things on the screen they get different gradients. Currently I have to embed the definitions for these gradients into all the svg files which makes changing the definitions tough. I'd like to have one single place to do this at. I suppose a possible option would be to combine all SVGs into a network heavy large file and then interact with the object to hide and show them. I'd prefer this approch if possible though.

Comment: Somebody else had the same problem with HTML files on a webserver and came up with a solution: dynamic webpages. Could you do a similar thing for your SVG files, have them dynamically generated on the server to avoid redundancy?

Answer (score 3):

The way you are referencing the gradient, it cannot work. You are first referencing the `<defs>` element in a `<use>` element, and then expect to find content inside that by its ID.

Everything referenced by a `<use>` element is not directly part of the parent DOM, but only part of an encapsulated shadow DOM. IDs defined inside it remain invisible outside of it.

Instead, nothing prevents you from referencing the external gradient directly, like this:

```
.someClass {
   fill: url(defs.svg#someGradient);
}
```

Comment: Interesting thought but doing it this way the defs.svg is never downloaded by the browser. Doesn't show in the network inspector. If use this CSS and also leave the `use` in the SVG I can see the file get downloaded but the style never applies.

Comment: For me, it works in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: Ok. I tried `fill: url('data:application/xml;utf8;<linearGradient></linearGradient>'` as well but it didn't work. I'll have to look for another solution.